# React Joi uri validation optional

Tags: reactjs, joi

I'm using Joi validation in React with this schema:

```
...
intro_video_link:
    Joi.string()
    .uri()
    .label("Intro Video"),
...
```

The `intro_video_link` is also required. I want Joi to validate field for uri if it is filled, but also allow it to be empty. There is no `.required()` called.

How?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably want to combine [`.allow()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyallowvalue) with [`.required()`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#anyrequired---aliases-exist):

```
 intro_video_link:  Joi.string().uri().label("Intro Video").required().allow('')
```

This way, the following objects will pass the validation:

```
{
   intro_video_link: ''
}


{
   intro_video_link: 'https://github.com'
}
```